# How do you evaluate an exponential term that contains both $-\infty$ and $+\infty$?

Tags: improper-integrals

What does $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{y(iu-\alpha)}dy = ?$ Please note $i$ is a complex variable, $\alpha$ and $u $ are constants.

I know this integral evaluates to:

$$\left.\frac{e^{y(iu-\alpha)}}{iu-\alpha}\right|_0^\infty$$

I'm unsure how this evaluates due to the terms inside the parenthesis of the exponetial for which $\infty$ will have to be distributed to.  So you end up with a $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ term inside that exponential, which is throwing me off.  How do you evaluate and make sense out of this?

Comment: What about $u$ and $\alpha$?  Are they complex?  Real?  Do you know anything else about them?

Comment: @David - I just edited my question to add more info about them.  Yes they can be treated like real constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that 
$\alpha$ is real.

Write
$e^{y(iu-\alpha)}
=e^{iuy}e^{-y\alpha}
$.

If $\alpha>0$,
$e^{-y\alpha}
\to 0
$,
so the limit at
$\infty$
is $0$.

If $\alpha=0$,
$e^{iuy}
=\cos(uy)+i\sin(uy)
$
oscillates as
$y \to \infty$,
so the limit does not exist.

If $\alpha < 0$,
it blows up as
$y \to \infty$.